# How to Ensure Player Input Doesn't Match Array Values in C#?

Tags: c#

Hello I am trying to figure out how to ensure that a player cant put a input thats already inside of an array. Here is my code

```
 using System;

class Program {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Bingo!");
    Console.WriteLine("To play bingo, you need 1 bingo card with 10 numbers between 1-20.");
    Console.WriteLine("Then, one number is randomly drawn, and if it matches any of the card's numbers, you get bingo.");

    Console.WriteLine("");

    int[] heltal = new int[10];
    Random slump = new Random();
    int slumpNummer = slump.Next(1, 21);

    for(int i = 0; i < heltal.Length; i++) {

      do {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter number {i + 1}:");
        int spelarInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      foreach(int j in heltal) {
        if (j == spelarInput) 
        {
         Console.WriteLine("You entered a number that has already been used. Please enter a different number.");
        } 
        else if (spelarInput > 20 || spelarInput < 1) 
        {
          Console.WriteLine("You entered a number outside the valid range. Please enter a number between 1 - 20."); 
        } 
        else 
          {
            heltal[i] = spelarInput;
            break; 
          }
        } 
      } while(true);
    }
      
    Console.WriteLine("Your numbers:");
    foreach(int i in heltal){
      Console.Write(i);
      Console.Write(" "); 
    }


    Console.WriteLine($"Bingo number {slumpNummer}");
    
    
  }
}
```

Right now the code is super broken and seems to think that I want to Console.Write the statements for every j in heltal

I know I can use bool somehow but I would like to not use that

Comment: Maybe consider using `HashSet<int>` ? Its `Add` method tells you if it was already included or if has been in fact added.

Comment: You may also want to revisit your logic. You don't need to check `else if (spelarInput > 20 || spelarInput < 1) ` for every `j in heltal`.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as something like

```
var numbers = new HashSet<int>();
while (numbers.Count < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enter number {numbers.Count + 1}:");
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Not a number");
    }
    else if (number < 1 || number > 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"outside range");
    }
    else if (!numbers.Add(number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Number already entered");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine($"Your Numbers: " + string.Join(", ", numbers.OrderBy(n => n)));
var randNumber = Random.Shared.Next(1, 21);
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Contains(randNumber)
    ? $"You won! winning number was {randNumber}"
    : $"You lost! winning number was {randNumber}");
```

This uses HashSet to ensure uniqueness, as well as a check to ensure the entered value is actually a number. This does not preserve the order the user entered the numbers, but that is probably not something the user would care about.

Comment: Side note: I suggest using `else if (...)` instead of `if (...) { ... continue;}` for code to be more readable